# onSavedInstanceState worked but correct results were not displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to make a small app practicing inter-fragment communication. Each time the button in the top-left fragment is clicked, the counter in the base fragment updates and displays the number of clicks.

I tried to use the onSaveInstanceState() method to preserve data so that upon rotations of the screen, the accumulated number of clicks could still be correctly presented. And by using the Log, I've seen the data being preserved during rotation, however, I do not understand why even though I set the content of the TextView using the preserved data, it would revert to the state as if the fragment was being first created.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.fragmenttrial;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Communicator {

    private static final String DT = "Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e(DT, "onCreate()");
        HelloFragment fragment1 = new HelloFragment();
        TrialFragment fragment2 = new TrialFragment();
        BaseFragment fragment3 = new BaseFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.hello_placeholder, fragment1, "myHelloFragment");
        transaction.replace(R.id.trial_placeholder, fragment2, "myTrialFragment");
        transaction.replace(R.id.base_placeholder, fragment3, "myBaseFragment");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        Log.e(DT,"onStart()");
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(DT, "onPause()");
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e(DT, "onResume()");
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.e(DT, "onRestart()");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e(DT, "onStop()");
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(DT, "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(DT, "onSaveInstanceState()");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.e(DT, "onCreateOptionsMenu()");
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        Log.e(DT, "onOptionsItemSelected");
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(int times) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.base_placeholder);
        fragment.changeData(times);
        if(times == 10) {
            SimpleFragment mFrag = new SimpleFragment();
            FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.trial_placeholder, mFrag);
            trans.commit();
        }

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fragmenttrial.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
    android:background="#0000FF">



    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/my_linear"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/hello_placeholder"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F2E0F7"
            />

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/trial_placeholder"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFF00"

            />

     </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/base_placeholder"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#DF013A"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Top left fragment(HelloFragment.java)

```
package com.example.fragmenttrial;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HelloFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int times = 0;
    Communicator comm;
    public static final String FT = "Fragment";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(FT, "onCreateView()-hello");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_frag, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(FT, "onCreate()-hello");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            //first time of creation
        } else {
            times = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");
        }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(FT, "onSaveInstanceState()-hello");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("counter", times);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        times++;
        comm.respond(times);
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        Log.i(FT, "onAttach()-hello");
        super.onAttach(activity);
        comm = (Communicator) activity;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(FT, "onActivityCreated()-hello");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(FT, "onViewStateRestored()-hello");
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        Log.i(FT, "onStart()-hello");
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        Log.i(FT, "onResume()-hello");
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(FT, "onPause()-hello");
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(FT, "onStop()-hello");
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(FT, "onDestroy()-hello");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        Log.i(FT, "onDestroyView()-hello");
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    public void onDetach() {
        Log.i(FT,"onDetach()-hello");
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

hello_frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">    
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#DA81F5"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

BaseFragment.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttrial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    int counter;
    TextView textView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(HelloFragment.FT, "onCreateView()-Base");

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_frag, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            //first time being created
        } else {
            counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter"); 
            System.out.println(counter);
            textView.setText("Button was clicked: " + counter + " times.");
            System.out.println(textView.getText().toString());
        }

        return v;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    } 

    public void changeData(int data) {
        counter = data;
        textView.setText("Button was clicked: " + data + " times.");
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(HelloFragment.FT,"onSaveInstanceState()-Base");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("counter", counter);
    }
}
```

base_frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#0B4C5F">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Number of clicks:  "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the log cat after rotating:

```
06-20 12:03:10.929: E/Activity(7185): onPause()
06-20 12:03:10.929: I/Fragment(7185): onPause()-hello
06-20 12:03:10.929: E/Activity(7185): onSaveInstanceState()
06-20 12:03:10.976: I/Fragment(7185): onSaveInstanceState()-hello
06-20 12:03:10.980: I/Fragment(7185): onSaveInstanceState()-Base
06-20 12:03:10.984: E/Activity(7185): onStop()
06-20 12:03:10.984: I/Fragment(7185): onStop()-hello
06-20 12:03:10.984: E/Activity(7185): onDestroy()
06-20 12:03:10.984: I/Fragment(7185): onDestroyView()-hello
06-20 12:03:10.988: I/Fragment(7185): onDestroy()-hello
06-20 12:03:10.988: I/Fragment(7185): onDetach()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.113: I/Fragment(7185): onAttach()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.113: I/Fragment(7185): onCreate()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.207: E/Activity(7185): onCreate()
06-20 12:03:11.211: E/Activity(7185): onStart()
06-20 12:03:11.211: I/Fragment(7185): onCreateView()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.218: I/Fragment(7185): onActivityCreated()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.218: I/Fragment(7185): onViewStateRestored()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.242: I/Fragment(7185): onCreateView()-Base
06-20 12:03:11.250: D/dalvikvm(7185): GC_CONCURRENT freed 153K, 3% free 8277K/8519K, paused 30ms+22ms, total 101ms
06-20 12:03:11.254: I/System.out(7185): 3
06-20 12:03:11.254: I/System.out(7185): Button was clicked: 3 times.
06-20 12:03:11.254: I/Fragment(7185): onDestroyView()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.254: I/Fragment(7185): onDestroy()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.254: I/Fragment(7185): onDetach()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.257: I/Fragment(7185): onAttach()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.257: I/Fragment(7185): onCreate()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.257: I/Fragment(7185): onCreateView()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.261: I/Fragment(7185): onActivityCreated()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.261: I/Fragment(7185): onViewStateRestored()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.261: I/Fragment(7185): onCreateView()-Base
06-20 12:03:11.269: I/Fragment(7185): onStart()-hello
06-20 12:03:11.269: E/Activity(7185): onCreateOptionsMenu()
06-20 12:03:11.273: E/Activity(7185): onResume()
06-20 12:03:11.273: I/Fragment(7185): onResume()-hello
```

It's seen that in the middle the textview text field was changed. However, when displayed it changes back to the initial state "Number of clicks: " as defined in the XML.

Comment: Try moving the whole if(savedInstanceState == null) else block to onActivityCreated, leaving the rest in onCreateView.

Comment: I don't know if you can use the same String as key for HelloFragment and BaseFragment. Try to use different unique keys.